# How to check if an element exists and only then run a test with Cypress?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I want to execute some function only when certain element is present using its data-test id.

Below is what I am trying to do:

```
cy.getByTestId('checkbox-id').then((el) => {
    if (el) {
        cy.tableSelectAll();
    }
}
```

Here I am expecting it to execute `tableSelectAll()` only if there is an element. But this fails saying it couldn't find an element with id "checkbox-id".

How can I fix this? Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to follow this pattern [Element existence](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing#Element-existence)

```js
cy.get('body')
  .then(($body) => {
    // synchronously query from body
    // to find which element was created
    if ($body.find('[data-testid="checkbox-id"]').length) {
      // checkbox-id was found
      cy.tableSelectAll()
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery method `.attr` to check the presence of the attribute `data-testid`.

```js
cy.get('checkbox-id').then(($ele) => {
  if ($ele.attr('data-testid')) {
    cy.tableSelectAll()
  } else {
    //Do something else
  }
})
```